When getting the system time why does everyone recommend getting the number of seconds since 1970?
My operating system, Windows, keeps track of the time and date, it's at the bottom right corner of the desktop. If I want to get the time and date, I'd expect a call (maybe a system call) that retrieves those values written at the bottom right of my screen. Instead the way people tell you to get the system time is by using functions and types such at std::chrono::clock::now and the C type time_t which are just a single (or maybe more) integer. Then there's another step. Usually this is demonstrated with logging that type, for example:
auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto legacyStart = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(start);
std::cout << std::ctime(&legacyStart) << '\n';

The conversion I'm guessing involves something like Zeller's Algorithm to calculate the day of the week from a certain time point.
My question is, is there a more efficient way to just read the system time from your operating system?
Also, on a related note, is this how the operating system does it? Keeps time by adding whatever time has passed to an integer (possibly the number of seconds since POSIX time), and then does a conversion every time to display that date and time?

"My question is, is there a more efficient way to just read the system time from your operating system?" Do you genuinely think the system stores the date and time in text or something?

Do you want to benchmark several ways for get time?

It's not so much "the way people tell you to get the system time" as "the way to get the system time". Maybe "the way that Windows tells you to get the system time", but the "people" (whoever they are) are just reporting the state of affairs, not recommending a certain approach.

@NicolBolas Yeah, why not? Or at least in a way that doesn't calculate that formula every time, like maybe a an integer for day of week, integer for day of month, etc.

Please define "efficient". You want the code runs efficiently or make developer productive? Maybe I get the question in a wrong way.

Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426575/is-time-t-returned-by-time-zone-specific

You mean is there a way to read the system time through the OS's API, yes, e.g. windows. Is it going to be faster/use less memory etc... probably not. Will it make your code harder to write probably yes

@JaMiT If I told you store the date, why wouldn't you store it as an integer for the day of the week, integer for day of the month, and an integer for the year instead of simply keeping a count of seconds, and then every time it's queried run that algorithm again?

Side note the 1970 comes from Unix, Unix time epoch and that just became a defacto standard.

@Zebrafish "If I told you store the date," -- Sorry, I'm not going to go along with a tangential discussion today. The telling in the question is about getting the date, not storing it.

There has to be a base from which you calculate the date. Is your question about why that particular date was chosen?

@Zebrafish because the most common uses of time in programming do not care about dates, but only about order and duration. There's also no such thing as "the date", thanks to timezones, leap seconds, DST and different calendars existing there are many dates and times corresponding to a single timestamp, making working with a single calendar representation impractical outside of simple applications that are free to ignore this reality because they're limited by locale.

Unix epoch timestamps are typically stored with 4 or 8 bytes. Those bytes can represent any time since Jan 1st 1970 down to the resolution of one second, up to Jan 2038 (in the case of a 32-bit value) or some time after the death of our sun, in the case of 64-bit values. You can add and subtract time as a simple integer operation. You can compare two times with an integer comparison. You do not have to be concerned with timezones. The storage is small, the calculations are fast, and it's not hard to convert it to a friendly text date. How is this not "efficient"?

@paddy OK, I guess Zeller's algorithm didn't look that efficient to me on Wikipedia.

Re "If I told you store the date, why wouldn't you store it as an integer for the day of the week, integer for day of the month, and an integer for the year instead of simply keeping a count of seconds, and then every time it's queried run that algorithm again?", But the OS has to do a lot more than "store the date". It has to be able to convert that date into different time zones. It has to synchronize that date with other systems. I that to communicate that date to different programs. It has to update that date millions of times a second.

@James -- there were lots of computers around long before 1970....

Some use the epoch since 1900.

@273K One uses 1601 Year of Our Lord, I think Apple?

From what I now it is the most memory and time efficient way to retrieve a date. Your computer uses the same trick. You can read more about it here, but in general, there is a clock that measure time since start of its life, regardless if its turned on or off (That's why you have current time even when you are offline). So OS just take this number and shows you in nice format, taking care about your timezone etc.
